# Echo the current file transfer with LFTP

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp, lftp

I'm trying to echo $file_name once the transfer is complete. However I cannot find any reference for how to create the variable in LFTP that displays the file name of what was just downloaded.

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
login="myusername"
pass="notmypassword"
host="my.hosting.server"
remote_dir='/Path/To/Remote/Dir/.'
local_dir="/Path/To/Local/Dir/"

file_name=**the name of the file im downloading**
base_name="$(basename "$0")"

lock_file="/tmp/$base_name.lock"
trap "rm -f $lock_file" SIGINT SIGTERM
if [ -e "$lock_file" ]
then
    echo "$base_name is running already."
    exit
else
    touch "$lock_file"
    lftp -u $login,$pass $host << EOF
    set ftp:ssl-allow no
    set mirror:use-pget-n 5
    mirror -c -x "\.r(a|[0-9])(r|[0-9])$" -P5 --log="/var/log/$base_name.log" "$remote_dir" "$local_dir"
    echo $file_name
    quit
EOF
    #osascript -e 'display notification "$file_name Downloaded" with title "Media Server"'
    rm -f "$lock_file"
    trap - SIGINT SIGTERM
    exit
fi
```

I figured that it would be rather simple to echo the current file and then also add this variable into my osascript to trigger a notification on OSX that a file has been successfully transferred, but for the life of me I can't figure out how.

What am I doing wrong???

Cheers!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "echo the current file transfer", what exactly would you like to display and where?

Comment: Sure thing, I'm when executing this shell script - once the file has successfully transferred - I want the terminal to echo the name of the file that was transferred.  For instance, if I was transferring: `remote_dir='/path/to/remote/directory/AwesomeMovie.mp4'` it would echo `AwesomeMovie.mp4`

Comment: To be more simplistic - I use LFTP to download files from my server to my home computer.  After the LFTP transfer is complete, my script echos "Movie Downloaded".  I want to replace the word 'Movie' with a variable that is the name of whatever file has been downloaded.  For instance if I have downloaded "Home Movie", the script echos "Home Movie Downloaded".  If I downloaded "Friend's Movie", the script echos "Friend's Movie Downloaded".   Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't have lftp currently installed but try using the verbose option with the mirror command and see if it outputs what you need.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately that won't do it for me.  The ultimate goal is to add this variable into an osascript display notification so that I have a OSX notification when the file has been successfully downloaded that also includes the **file name of what i've downloaded**.  Thats the key here.  As far as I know, you can't save verbose as a variable.

Comment: Does the verbose option display the file names?  If so, then try redirecting the output of the here doc to a temp file, then clean up the temp file using awk so that it contains only the file names, then in a for loop display your message.

Comment: on the 80% solution with 20% effort side, does replacing `echo $file` with `dir $file` (or `ls $file`) get you any useful output? Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This script will echo each file that was transferred, feel free to clean it up and modify it to suit your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script started."

download_directory="${HOME}/downloads/"
echo "Downloading to ${download_directory}"

rm ${download_directory}/*

download_log=$(mktemp)
lftp <<- EOF > ${download_log}
    # elided connection details, enter your own
    open 
    mirror -v . ${download_directory}
    quit
EOF

cat ${download_log} | awk ' { print $3 } ' | sed 's/`//' | sed 's/'\''//' | xargs echo "Downloaded:"
rm -f ${download_log}
echo "Script successfully ended."
```

Example output:

```
=> ./foobar.sh  
Script started.
Downloading to /home/downloads/
Downloaded: something1.yes testfile.txt
Script successfully ended.
```

Comment: Why the hell would you `rm ${download_directory}/*` though - that line looks like its up to no good...

Comment: @ThatsNoMoon I wanted to empty my downloads directory before I downloaded anything, feel free to remove that line if that's not what you would like to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use a file verification script:

```
set xfer:verify on
set xfer:verify-command /home/user/bin/file-transferred
```

The script output (FD 1,2) is redirected, but you can use `/dev/tty` to output the file name to the terminal:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1" >/dev/tty
```

Alternatively, open another descriptor:

```
lftp 3>&1 <<EOF
...
EOF
```

and redirect output there:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1" >&3
```